# What file type would be ideal for this situation?

Tags: python, json, file, format

I have a Python program that uses Selenium to **scrape** some data from a website every X minutes.
Every sample is represented as a tuple, with a boolean and datetime, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime


result = (True, datetime.now())
```

Usually I save my samples in a database which is very easy to do, but this time I need to save them to a file.
So, after each sampling I need to open the file, and append the result tuple.

Initially I used JSON, however, in order to append new data it is necessary to first use `json.load` then append the result and `json.dump` it again.

However, since Im going to have to deal with large number of samples eventually the process of appending would slow down dramatically since I have to read the whole file before writing again.

So, JSON is probably not a good format to use here. What other format would allow me to write the tuples, and later read them easily? (= without having to parse them into tuples again myself character after character).

Comment: since text files are easy and support the `open('a')` mode very well I can only suggest that. You could technically just make your tuple into a string "True, formated_date" and save it in a `.txt` file but since it is comma delimited you could even just save it as a `.csv` file. Obviously when reading it back you will have to parse your date string to actual date but this shouldn't be hard if you use a single format.

Comment: I think I found a solution to my problem: there's a format named pickle, which stores python objects in binary format and then reads them to back to objects.

Comment: oh yea pickling is great. just make sure you always have compatible versions of python when unpickling the data.